# using for loop to count list elements in a string

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, user-defined-functions

Im beginner in python, learning it for biology purposes.

Ok, lets suppose I want to write a function that will iterate over a list to count how many of its elements in the string using for loop

```
def counting(string,lista):
    for element in lista:
        element_count=string.count(element)
    return element_count
```

so when using the above function to find how many A and C in my string

```
print(counting('AABCDEF',['A','C']))
```

It seems the function only return the count of C in the string which is 1, what I want to get both elements count. It seems adding a print line inside the loop body will solve the problem,

```
def counting(string,lista):
    for element in lista:
        element_count=string.count(element)
        print(element_count)
    return element_count
```

is there a way to get the same output without using the print statement?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Return the result as a list.

```
def counting(string,lista):
    temp = []
    for element in lista:
        temp.append(string.count(element))
    return temp

print(counting('AABCDEF',['A','C']))
```

The result is

```
[2, 1]
```

---

To print some verbose,

```
def counting(string, lista):
    temp = []
    for element in lista:
        temp.append('{} count is {}'.format(element, string.count(element)))
    return ', '.join(temp)

print(counting('AABCDEF', ['A','C']))
```

Then

```
A count is 2, C count is 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what if I want it to give me the output in more verbose way for example getting output like 'A count is 2, C count is 1'